# Unity Inspector suddenly shows NaN values

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had a perfectly working scene until yesterday no changes were made to it,
Suddenly one control the ScrollView started turning all its children Transform values to NaN in the inspector, and stopped working as intended means none of the items added to the child panel will appear for that reason.

Here are some screenshots of my settings maybe someone can en-light me as to why this strange behavior occurred:

[image: Hierarchy]

[image: Scroll View Settings]
[image: Panel Settings]

No new scripts that mess with the editor where added (I only use UGUI for my anchors but it was there all along)
Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Found the issue to be connected to my Main Camera although I didn't touch it ,
When I turn my canvas to Screen Space Overlay instead of the current setting 
Screen Space Camera the issue goes away.  so here is a screenshot of my Main Camera settings.
[image: Main Camera Settings]

Comment: Can't tell what the issue is. But its always better to have a viewport object as first-level child of scrollview and it should be assigned into viewport reference field in scrollview component and content panel should be a child of view-port. This might help

Comment: yeah it was like that I was just messing around with stuff to see what causes the problem it has nothing to do with the view port , actually the viewport and the child "Content"  had also these same NaN values